# CSS column layout - re-order items on mobile

Tags: html, css

This is what I want to achieve:

**Desktop**

2 column layout with items of variable height.  1 column with a fixed width of 400px and the other fills up the rest of the width.

[image: 2 column layout with items of variable height.]

**Mobile**

1 column layout with items re-ordered as shown.

[image: 1 column layout with items re-ordered as shown.]

Either layout on it's own is easy enough to do.  But I'm not sure how to combine both layouts. The tricky part is re-ordering the items I think. Is this possible with CSS alone?

Comment: Do you try media-query? You can set `width: 100%` to all item when screen width is mobile

Comment: Yes.  Media queries will be used.  But the tricky part is trying to re-order the items on mobile.  I know that you can re-order items with flex, but how would I combine the desktop view with a 2 column layout, where some items from the 2nd column will come before items from the 1st column on mobile?

Comment: What about it? 
`<div id="2"/> <div id="1"/>`. Then you can use `float` to spilit to 2 column

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely easy with CSS Grid: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: I tried grid but it didn't seem to work with the variable heights of the items.   (ex: item 1 and item 3 would be forced to have the same height, and 2 and 4 would also be forced to have the same height.  Not what I want.) Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: You could create three rows and have 2 and 3 span two rows.